# flyway mysqldump migration

Tags: java, mysql, database-migration, flyway

The more I understand how flyway works for database migration, the better I like it.

I am trying to get flyway to read migrations generated from a mysqldump -d and I stumbled upon some weird behavior.

On the homepage it says

> DDL exported by mysqldump can be used unchanged in a Flyway migration.

My experience is a bit different. **How do you use the files generated by mysqldump with flyway?**

---

**What I was trying:**

I tried getting the DDL by using

```
mysqldump -h host --user=user -p -d --hex-blob databasename > V1__Basic.sql
```

This does work and gives me a file which looks something like this (yes it's a database scheme from Activiti :) ):

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.6 (i386)
--
-- Host: host    Database: database
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.27-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`   
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY` (
  `ID_` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `REV_` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME_` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPLOYMENT_ID_` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `BYTES_` longblob,
  `GENERATED_` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_`),
  KEY `ACT_FK_BYTEARR_DEPL` (`DEPLOYMENT_ID_`),
  CONSTRAINT `ACT_FK_BYTEARR_DEPL` FOREIGN KEY (`DEPLOYMENT_ID_`) REFERENCES     `ACT_RE_DEPLOYMENT` (`ID_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `ACT_GE_PROPERTY`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACT_GE_PROPERTY`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

And so on.

I have flyway setup (simple spring integration) and it is picking up the files.
However it doesn't do anything (no sql is executed):

```
INFO  @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,646 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
INFO  @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,647 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,649 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Successfully completed and committed migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,651 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Finished migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 (execution time 00:00.002s)
```

However if I remove all lines before the first SQL statement (`DROP TABLE`) flyway executes only the drop table and stops afterwards.

```
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,698 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Found statement at line 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,698 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript - Executing SQL: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,700 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Successfully completed and committed migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1
DEBUG @ 14 Mar 2013 22:34:41,700 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Finished migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1 (execution time 00:00.004s)
```

If I remove everything up to the `CREATE TABLE`flyway doesn't like the syntax

```
ERROR @ 14 Mar 2013 22:45:01,270 @ com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate - Caused by org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ""ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY"" (
  ""ID_"" VARCHAR(64) COLLATE[*] UTF8_BIN NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

How can I get the output of mysqldump to something flyway will like?
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway's parser is DB-specific. Since you are trying to import into H2, it tries to parse H2 syntax and not mysql syntax. Import it into a mysql DB and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have MySQL for testing and production and an H2 for unit testing. My idea was to extract the DDL from the production DB and use this as the basis for all environments. If I understood you correctly this does not work. Does this mean I will have to have separate scripts for unit testing and production for both the V1 and all other versions. Is this correct?

Comment: You can clean the dump so it is compatible with H2 and make sure future migrations use syntax compatible with both DBs. Or go for the better option: use mysql in dev and remove another difference with your prod environment.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing for now, thanks! I cleaned the MySQL dump. It does make sense to move this to MySQL in the future, though.